# How to define threadprivate variables for class member variables

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm writing a multi-threaded object oriented c++ code via OpenMP. For the sake of simplicity and generality I'm obliged to define some of my variables and functions in a template class. I want to make them `threadprivate` to exploit the persistence features of thread-private variables and be able to use them in other functions or source files embedded in or calling the template class. but I receive the following error:
"**... is not file, namespace, or block scope variable**"
I know that I can only use `threadprivate` directive for file, namespace, or block scope variables but I was wondering if there's any alternative to apply `threadprivate` directive for class members too. My total code layout is like:

```
template<typename T> class EntContainer
{
private:
T** empties;
e_NumPointers;
e_nLists;
.
.
.
public:
#pragma omp threadprivate(empties, e_NumPointers, e_nLists)
void function
{
// do some paralle stuff using #pragma omp parallel 
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you declare them as `static` class members, will OpenMPI allow them to be threadprivate?

Comment: It looks like you are mistaking the MPI implementation Open MPI with the threading paradigm OpenMP.

Comment: No!! declaring them as static does not help

Answer (score 0):

> OpenMP 3.0 draft allows threadprivate on static class members, but
>    #pragma omp threadprivate must be present inside of the definition of
>   the class containing the threadprivate static class member, and must
>   lexically preceed all uses. [source](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2008-02/msg01283.html)

Making the members static and moving the #pragma omp threadprivate directive right below their declarations should fix the error.